# How to get GridView item from AutomationElement?

Tags: .net, ui-automation

I can get the AutomationElement for a ListView/GridView with the `FindAll` method. The classname for the individual items in a row is *ContentPresenter*. I would like to get the value but I can only get their position (column, row).

I have tried many patterns in the ValuePattern is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this is not possible with .NET UIAutomation. The strings underlying the GridView are too *dumb*. If there is a TextBox in the GridView it is possible to get it and manipulate it using the `ValuePattern`.

You could also add an intelligent kind of *label* implementation which supports the `ValuePattern`. This was not possible in my case but might be if you program both sides of the UIAutomation by yourself.